# How to make Dependency Track to suppress certain VULs?

Tags: open-source, owasp

Some VULs are definitely false, for an example CVE-2022-28111.
So we need to configure Dependency Track to ignore such VULs, then we could get less false notifications.
I have tried to use **.dependency-track/dependency-check/suppressions.xml** or **.dependency-track/suppressions.xml** file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suppressions>
<suppress>
   <notes><![CDATA[
    Ignored CVEs
   ]]></notes>
  <cve>CVE-2022-22965</cve>
  <cve>GHSA-36p3-wjmg-h94x</cve>
  <cve>sonatype-2022-1764</cve>
  <cve>CVE-2022-28111</cve>
  <cve>GHSA-w559-623p-vfg8</cve>
</suppress>
</suppressions>
```

But no luck! I have searched a lot, but still no clue.